# AppDelegate retuning null when calling an instance objective c ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, appdelegate

I'm trying to call a function implemented in the AppDelegate in XCode project from anther class in my project. 
It does not show any errors at complile time but when I run the project

> :libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type
>   NSException:

error occurs. I added break points at places to check where it crashes and found out that this happens in the other class on which I call a function in my AppDelegate

My AppDelegate is:

```
int idval;
@implementation AppDelegate

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application
            openURL:(NSURL *)url
  sourceApplication:(NSString *)sourceApplication
         annotation:(id)annotation{
    NSString *urll=url.path.lastPathComponent;
    if ([urll isEqual:[NSNull null]]){
        urll=@ "-1";
    }
    idval=[urll intValue];
    NSLog(@ "%@",urll);    return true;
}
- (int) fetchID{
    return idval;
}
```

My class where I call the `fetchId` method is
//fetch the ID from AppDelegate

```
int fetchID()
{
    AppDelegate *appDelegate = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
   int ids=[appDelegate fetchID];
    NSLog(@ "%i",ids);
    return ids;
}

extern "C"
{
   const int _getId()
    {

        int idval= fetchID();
        return idval;
    }
```

A `null` value is returned at the place where AppDelegate is defined, and from the very next line the app crashes.

I'm new to iOS. I tried many suggestions and solutions but nothing came a good fit for my problem. Please point me in the correct direction. I'm trying to implement a deeplink for a unity powered mobile application via XCode

complete error message which Im getting in the console

```
    2016-03-07 15:42:10.914 LiveRoom[1173:1362453] -> registered mono modules 0x1016ae5f0
2016-03-07 15:42:11.372 LiveRoom[1173:1362453] You've implemented -[<UIApplicationDelegate> application:didReceiveRemoteNotification:fetchCompletionHandler:], but you still need to add "remote-notification" to the list of your supported UIBackgroundModes in your Info.plist.
-> applicationDidFinishLaunching()
-> applicationDidBecomeActive()
Renderer: Apple A7 GPU
Vendor:   Apple Inc.
Version:  OpenGL ES 2.0 Apple A7 GPU - 75.11.5
GLES:     2
GL_OES_depth_texture GL_OES_depth_texture_cube_map GL_OES_depth24 GL_OES_element_index_uint GL_OES_fbo_render_mipmap GL_OES_mapbuffer GL_OES_packed_depth_stencil GL_OES_rgb8_rgba8 GL_OES_standard_derivatives GL_OES_texture_float GL_OES_texture_half_float GL_OES_texture_half_float_linear GL_OES_vertex_array_object GL_EXT_blend_minmax GL_EXT_color_buffer_half_float GL_EXT_debug_label GL_EXT_debug_marker GL_EXT_discard_framebuffer GL_EXT_draw_instanced GL_EXT_instanced_arrays GL_EXT_map_buffer_range GL_EXT_occlusion_query_boolean GL_EXT_pvrtc_sRGB GL_EXT_read_format_bgra GL_EXT_separate_shader_objects GL_EXT_shader_framebuffer_fetch GL_EXT_shader_texture_lod GL_EXT_shadow_samplers GL_EXT_sRGB GL_EXT_texture_filter_anisotropic GL_EXT_texture_rg GL_EXT_texture_storage GL_APPLE_clip_distance GL_APPLE_color_buffer_packed_float GL_APPLE_copy_texture_levels GL_APPLE_framebuffer_multisample GL_APPLE_rgb_422 GL_APPLE_sync GL_APPLE_texture_format_BGRA8888 GL_APPLE_texture_max_level GL_APPLE_texture_packed_float GL_IMG_r

ead_format GL_IMG_texture_compression_pvrtc 
OPENGL LOG: Creating OpenGL ES 2.0 graphics device
Initialize engine version: 5.3.1f1 (cc9cbbcc37b4)
WARNING: Shader Unsupported: 'Standard' - Pass 'FORWARD' has no vertex shader
WARNING: Shader Unsupported: 'Standard' - Pass 'FORWARD_DELTA' has no vertex shader
WARNING: Shader Unsupported: 'Standard' - Pass 'SHADOWCASTER' has no vertex shader
WARNING: Shader Unsupported: 'Standard' - All passes removed
UnloadTime: 9.839791 ms
Setting BehaviourComponentFactory
Vuforia.ComponentFactoryStarterBehaviour:SetBehaviourComponentFactory()
Vuforia.ComponentFactoryStarterBehaviour:Awake()
UnityEngine.GameObject:AddComponent()

(Filename: /Users/builduser/buildslave/unity/build/artifacts/generated/common/runtime/UnityEngineDebugBindings.gen.cpp Line: 37)

2016-03-07 15:42:13.230 LiveRoom[1173:1362453] -[VuforiaNativeRendererController fetchID]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x126db7510
2016-03-07 15:42:13.315 LiveRoom[1173:1362453] Uncaught exception: NSInvalidArgumentException: -[VuforiaNativeRendererController fetchID]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x126db7510
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000182401918 <redacted> + 148
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x0000000181a6ff80 objc_exception_throw + 56
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x000000018240861c <redacted> + 0
    3   CoreFoundation                      0x00000001824055b8 <redacted> + 872
    4   CoreFoundation                      0x000000018230968c _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 92
    5   LiveRoom                            0x000000010010b730 _Z7fetchIDv + 100
    6   LiveRoom                            0x000000010012cad8 QRCodeScanner_Start_m1917009403_0 + 316
    7   LiveRoom                            0x0000000100750648 _Z33RuntimeInvoker_Void_t_224166001_0PK10MethodInfoPvPS2_ + 28
    8   LiveRoom                            0x0000000101528b9c _ZN6il2cpp2vm7Runtime6InvokeEPK10MethodInfoPvPS5_PP12Il2CppObject + 68
    9   LiveRoom                            0x0000000100edbc20 _ZN19ScriptingInvocation6InvokeEPP18ScriptingExceptionb + 56
    10  LiveRoom                            0x0000000100ed1ef4 _ZN13MonoBehaviour30InvokeMethodOrCoroutineCheckedE21ScriptingMethodIl2CppP15ScriptingObjectPP18ScriptingException + 1076
    11  LiveRoom                            0x0000000100ed20d8 _ZN13MonoBehaviour30InvokeMethodOrCoroutineCheckedE21ScriptingMethodIl2CppP15ScriptingObject + 52
    12  LiveRoom                            0x0000000100dba220 _ZN18DelayedCallManager6UpdateEi + 668
    13  LiveRoom                            0x0000000100e8bb2c _Z10PlayerLoopbbP10IHookEvent + 496
    14  LiveRoom                            0x000000010106a028 _ZL19UnityPlayerLoopImplb + 20
    15  LiveRoom                            0x00000001000f71fc UnityRepaint + 328
    16  LiveRoom                            0x0000000100107528 -[UnityAppController(ViewHandling) showGameUI] + 192
    17  LiveRoom                            0x0000000100103c48 -[UnityAppController startUnity:] + 284
    18  Foundation                          0x0000000182db644c __NSFireDelayedPerform + 428
    19  CoreFoundation                      0x00000001823b95f4 <redacted> + 28
    20  CoreFoundation                      0x00000001823b9298 <redacted> + 884
    21  CoreFoundation                      0x00000001823b69ac <redacted> + 1520
    22  CoreFoundation                      0x00000001822e5680 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 384
    23  GraphicsServices                    0x00000001837f4088 GSEventRunModal + 180
    24  UIKit                               0x000000018715cd90 UIApplicationMain + 204
    25  LiveRoom                            0x00000001000f110c main + 156
    26  libdyld.dylib                       0x0000000181e868b8 <redacted> + 4
)
2016-03-07 15:42:13.317 LiveRoom[1173:1362453] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[VuforiaNativeRendererController fetchID]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x126db7510'
*** First throw call stack:
(0x182401900 0x181a6ff80 0x18240861c 0x1824055b8 0x18230968c 0x10010b730 0x10012cad8 0x100750648 0x101528b9c 0x100edbc20 0x100ed1ef4 0x100ed20d8 0x100dba220 0x100e8bb2c 0x10106a028 0x1000f71fc 0x100107528 0x100103c48 0x182db644c 0x1823b95f4 0x1823b9298 0x1823b69ac 0x1822e5680 0x1837f4088 0x18715cd90 0x1000f110c 0x181e868b8)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
(lldb)
```

Comment: Could you show us the whole error message (what's after "uncaught exception of type NSException:")?

Comment: `unrecognized selector sent to instance` is a well known issue. You are calling `fetchID` on an object of class `VuforiaNativeRendererController` which doesn't know this method. So try to find which lines exactly is causing the issue, and what's the class of the object...

Comment: Add an exception breakpoint in the debugger

Comment: Have you exposed the method in the AppDelegate's @interface declaration in it's header file?

Comment: @ZeMoon yes the problem was with the VuforiaNativeRendererController  as said above. That solved the deep link problem I had